# How is short-term borrowing by banks in the US performed?

Tags: banking, financial-economics, bonds

I read a statement that one reason for persistent demand for US Treasuries is that US banks buy them because they can be used as collateral for acquiring short-term debt.

I don't understand this. If a bank can borrow at the Fed window, then why not borrow short-term if you need short term or long-term if you need long term.

Why would you lend money by buying treasuries and then borrow short-term using those as collateral. It makes no sense. Borrow short term from whom?

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a number of questions; I'll answer three.

1. *If a bank can borrow at the Fed window, then why not borrow short-term if you need short term or long-term if you need long term.*

Banks are strongly discouraged from borrowing from the Fed. Doing so is expensive and an indicator of institutional distress.

2. *Why would you lend money by buying treasuries and then borrow short-term using those as collateral.*

The same reason that banks borrow short and lend long in any other context: short rates are lower than long rates, so the bank earns a spread.

3. *Borrow short term from whom?*

Money market mutual funds, mostly.